# How can I specific Windows sharing folder port?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I have a NAS server(IP: 192.168.0.101) in my studio, and I mapped it's 137/138/139/445 port to my Internet IP(2.2.2.2) by router. The correspondence is:
192.168.0.101:137 <=> 2.2.2.2:30137
192.168.0.101:138 <=> 2.2.2.2:30138
192.168.0.101:139 <=> 2.2.2.2:30139
192.168.0.101:445 <=> 2.2.2.2:30445
Now, there is a server hosted in IDC and it need to access the sharing folder.
How can I specific the sharing folder port from 137/138/139/445 to 30137/30138/30139/30445 in IDC hosting server?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your version is better
192.168.0.101:137 <=> 2.2.2.2:137
192.168.0.101:138 <=> 2.2.2.2:138
192.168.0.101:139 <=> 2.2.2.2:139
192.168.0.101:445 <= > 2.2.2.2:445

and then IDC will be able to connect through 2.2.2.2

Comment: But 2.2.2.2:137/138/139/445 has been used by another NAS server, which LAN IP is 192.168.0.100.